# MS Project - Measuring Tasks by Days

Tags: ms-project, scheduling

Is there a way to discard of hourly measurement in MS Project, and instead having it track only the amount of days I input?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can track your tasks by days but you need to define **the hours per day**.

Look at it this way.

1. For a shift worker, a day is 12 hours
2. For for an office staff, a day is 8 hours
3. For an equipment, a day is 24 hours

The system needs a way to know what constitute a "day"

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is, "no". Regardless of how you enter work or duration, internally Project tracks everything to the nearest minute. If your end goal is to set up your plan for a "day rate" (i.e. a resource charges by the day regardless of whether that resource works 1 hour, 8 hours, or whatever), then you will need a VBA macro to convert everything into a day rate.